# How should I go about printing all elements in an ArrayList via a toString in a formatted manner?

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, tostring

What I am asking is that, in Java 8, when I call my `toString()` method (overridden), I am trying to print out the elements of each respective `ArrayList<String>` in this manner:

```
- str1
- str2
- str3
```

But instead, when I return the `ArrayList<String>`, it is printed in this manner:

```
[str1, str2, str3]
```

It makes perfect sense to me why it is printed that way, but I'm not sure how I would go about changing how it is displayed in the `toString()`.
Note that this `ArrayList<String>` varies in size depending on the object of which it is apart of, and I would rather not use an external method to print these elements out in such a manner unless there was no other way to do it.

Furthermore, I don't think it even makes sense to have a for loop within a `toString()` printing out the elements of the `ArrayList<String>` in the aforementioned manner, and I don't think Java would allow that anyway.

Comment: you may also want to look at [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) to create a string representation of a streamable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to write a custom `List`-implementation to wrap a list in and then override `toString()`. This seems pretty overkill. Instead, I suggest printing the entries of the `List` with the help of the [`Stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
list.forEach(entry -> System.out.println("- " + entry));
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/kGXf9h)

With the advent of the new instance method [`String::formatted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#formatted(java.lang.Object...)) (currently a preview feature), we could also write

```
list.stream()
    .map("- %s"::formatted)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

(Sorry, no <kbd>Ideone demo</kbd> for this one, Ideone runs on Java 12)

Answer (score 0):

I would just create another method like displayArrayPretty(ArrayList arr) where you loop through and print how you want. Ex.

```
for (String str: arr) {
System.out.println("- " + str);
}
```

Comment: The `"\n"` leads to double blank lines.